# Apache htaccess rule for url shortening

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-shortener

I'm trying to create something 
short.com/ASWi7 -> short.com/index.php?h=ASWi7

so I tried using this code on my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?hash=$1   [L]
```

but the website loses the css and everything...i organized my site in folder etc...
so how can i exclude all the folders or cetain files to be part of that rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?hash=$1   [L]
```

`!-f` checks for existing files

`!-d` checks for existing directories

Hope that helps.